# Flowable: CMMN modeler error converting CasePlanModel

Tags: java, bpmn, flowable

I've deployed Flowable 6.3.1 through Apache tomcat.
Trying to model the following model the `Flowable BpmnJsonConverter` (which by the way I've got no idea what it has to do with CMMN modeling) throws `NullPointerException`.
[CMMN model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9wu8.png)

The generated xml is as follows.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/CMMN/20151109/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:flowable="http://flowable.org/cmmn" xmlns:cmmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/CMMN/20151109/CMMNDI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/CMMN/20151109/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/CMMN/20151109/DI" targetNamespace="http://www.flowable.org/casedef">
  <case id="holidayRequest" name="HolidayRequest" flowable:initiatorVariableName="initiator">
    <casePlanModel id="casePlanModel" flowable:formKey="requestHoliday">
      <planItem id="planItem1" name="checkRequest" definitionRef="sid-0F1F1EF4-7661-4CC8-9AD7-4F2566DF989C">
        <entryCriterion id="sid-43F0EC01-FD2F-417C-9CC7-46F0F3141D40" sentryRef="sentry1"></entryCriterion>
      </planItem>
      <planItem id="planItem2" name="isCheckNeeded" definitionRef="sid-C7C05BD3-1D12-4060-9AE8-FD5E4CB9DF94">
        <itemControl>
          <requiredRule></requiredRule>
        </itemControl>
      </planItem>
      <sentry id="sentry1">
        <ifPart>
          <condition><![CDATA[${decisionNeeded == "true"}]]></condition>
        </ifPart>
      </sentry>
      <humanTask id="sid-0F1F1EF4-7661-4CC8-9AD7-4F2566DF989C" name="checkRequest" flowable:candidateUsers="admin,boss" flowable:formKey="checkHoliday"></humanTask>
      <decisionTask id="sid-C7C05BD3-1D12-4060-9AE8-FD5E4CB9DF94" name="isCheckNeeded" isBlocking="false">
        <extensionElements>
          <flowable:field name="decisionTaskThrowErrorOnNoHits">
            <flowable:string><![CDATA[false]]></flowable:string>
          </flowable:field>
        </extensionElements>
      </decisionTask>
    </casePlanModel>
  </case>
  <cmmndi:CMMNDI>
    <cmmndi:CMMNDiagram id="CMMNDiagram_holidayRequest">
      <cmmndi:CMMNShape id="CMMNShape_casePlanModel" cmmnElementRef="casePlanModel">
        <dc:Bounds height="424.0" width="580.0" x="40.0" y="40.0"></dc:Bounds>
        <cmmndi:CMMNLabel></cmmndi:CMMNLabel>
      </cmmndi:CMMNShape>
      <cmmndi:CMMNShape id="CMMNShape_planItem1" cmmnElementRef="planItem1">
        <dc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="300.0" y="180.0"></dc:Bounds>
        <cmmndi:CMMNLabel></cmmndi:CMMNLabel>
      </cmmndi:CMMNShape>
      <cmmndi:CMMNShape id="CMMNShape_sid-43F0EC01-FD2F-417C-9CC7-46F0F3141D40" cmmnElementRef="sid-43F0EC01-FD2F-417C-9CC7-46F0F3141D40">
        <dc:Bounds height="22.0" width="14.0" x="292.58765691867626" y="227.54247101841793"></dc:Bounds>
        <cmmndi:CMMNLabel></cmmndi:CMMNLabel>
      </cmmndi:CMMNShape>
      <cmmndi:CMMNShape id="CMMNShape_planItem2" cmmnElementRef="planItem2">
        <dc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="105.5" y="183.0"></dc:Bounds>
        <cmmndi:CMMNLabel></cmmndi:CMMNLabel>
      </cmmndi:CMMNShape>
      <cmmndi:CMMNEdge id="CMMNEdge_sid-BDE0FC41-0461-4EAB-93E8-4E3E19709E7B" cmmnElementRef="sid-C7C05BD3-1D12-4060-9AE8-FD5E4CB9DF94" targetCMMNElementRef="sid-0F1F1EF4-7661-4CC8-9AD7-4F2566DF989C">
        <di:waypoint x="205.44999999999806" y="222.2287917737789"></di:waypoint>
        <di:waypoint x="299.99999999999847" y="220.77043701799485"></di:waypoint>
        <cmmndi:CMMNLabel></cmmndi:CMMNLabel>
      </cmmndi:CMMNEdge>
    </cmmndi:CMMNDiagram>
  </cmmndi:CMMNDI>
</definitions>
```

what do I need to do to fix it?

P.S. I previously had this problem and when I’ve tried to deploy it’s app it used to throw an Exception saying about `extensionElement` tag and the fact that it should not have child! but now it deploys without any exception.

EDIT-1: I've figured out the decision table reference was null so when I changed it to point out the decision table I got the same exception I mentioned previously in P.S. part. It's a CmmnXMLException. The stack-trace summary is as follows.

> ERROR 19300 --- [nio-8090-exec-8]
> o.f.u.m.s.ModelImageService              : Error creating thumbnail
> cmmn image 073fbc3d-b36b-11e8-ae0a-005056c00008
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> org.flowable.cmmn.image.impl.DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.connectionPerfectionizer(DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.java:393)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-image-generator-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]  at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.image.impl.DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.drawAssociation(DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.java:369)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-image-generator-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]  at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.image.impl.DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.generateCaseDiagram(DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.java:261)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-image-generator-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]  at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.image.impl.DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.generateImage(DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.java:222)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-image-generator-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]  at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.image.impl.DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.generateImage(DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.java:227)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-image-generator-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]  at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.image.impl.DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.generatePngImage(DefaultCaseDiagramGenerator.java:232)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-image-generator-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
>
> ERROR 19300 --- [nio-8090-exec-8]
> o.f.c.e.i.i.CommandContext: Error while closing command
> context
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.converter.CmmnXMLException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d:
> Invalid content was found starting with element 'extensionElements'.
> No child element is expected at this point.   at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.converter.CmmnXmlConverter.convertToCmmnModel(CmmnXmlConverter.java:173)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-converter-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]    at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.engine.impl.parser.CmmnParserImpl.parse(CmmnParserImpl.java:89)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-engine-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]   at
>
> org.flowable.cmmn.engine.impl.parser.CmmnParserImpl.parse(CmmnParserImpl.java:67)
> ~[flowable-cmmn-engine-6.3.1.jar:6.3.1]
>
> Caused by:
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content
> was found starting with element 'extensionElements'. No child element
> is expected at this point.    at
> org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
> Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar:?]
>
> ERROR 19300 --- [nio-8090-exec-2]
> o.f.u.m.s.AppDefinitionPublishService    : Invalid deploy result code:
> HTTP/1.1 500

EDIT-2: I tried to build the Case step by step and found out the CasePlanModel crashes in saving when a form is added to it. Also the modeler and engine has sever problems integrating decision task references.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest 6.4.0 version? Does the same error occur there?

Answer (score 0):

Last parameter of your definition tag is wrong:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.flowable.org/casedef"
```

should be:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.flowable.org/processdef"
```